# I can't update from within a facet

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.3 with JSF 2.1. In the code below, I have a primeFaces dataTable that contains rows of data drawn from the database which is correctly activated from a tree component on the left part of my page. The dataTable displays and behaves correctly. I have a delete functionality that calls "update" which refreshes my dataTable and reflects my changes after the database was updated. My problem is with with f:facet (id="header"). Contained in that facet is a commandLink that creates a new row in my dataTable. It works in the sense that my database is correctly updated. The dataTable is not refreshed after this. In order to refresh my dataTable, I have to click on another node in my tree component (on the left of the page) and then return to the original treeNode to see my dataTable perfectly updated. What can I add to my code to update the dataTable dynamically?
Unfortunately, I can't add all my permutations that I've tried here - I've spent a long time on this problem - and your inputs will be greatly appreciated!

```
    <h:form id="formRight" >            
    <p:dataTable var="material" value="#{entityCrudTreeBean.materialList}" id="materials" editable="true" paginator="true" rows="10" sortBy="#{material.name}">
                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{entityCrudTreeBean.onEditRow}"/>
                <f:facet id="header" name="header">
                    In-Cell Material Editing
                    <br />
                    <p:commandLink id="create" value="Add new material" action="#{entityCrudTreeBean.createNewMaterial}" update=":formRight"/>
                </f:facet>
                <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:125px">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        ...
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Options" style="width:10px" >
                    <p:rowEditor />
                    <p:commandLink id="delete" action="#{entityCrudTreeBean.deleteRow(material)}" update=":formRight">
                        <h:graphicImage value="#{resource['icons:Delete-icon.png']}" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

edit:
changing the line to
`<p:commandLink id="create" value="Add new material" action="#{entityCrudTreeBean.createNewMaterial}" update=":formRight:materials"/>`
doesn't work either
edit:
changing to :
`<f:facet id="header" name="header">
                        In-Cell Material Editing
                        <br />
                        <p:commandLink id="create" value="Add new material" ajax="true" process="@this" action="#{entityCrudTreeBean.createNewMaterial}" update="@form"/>
                 </f:facet>`
doesn't solve the problem either.

Comment: haven't read the whole question (just the subject)... try to replace `update=":formRight"` with `update="@form"`

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  Unfortunately, `code: <p:commandLink id="create" value="Add new material" action="#{entityCrudTreeBean.createNewMaterial}" update="@form"/>` doesn't work either

Comment: any chance that `<h:form id="formRight" >  ` is being wrapped by some other form ?

Comment: no, it's part of `<ui:define name="centreContent">`.  And id="delete" is working well.

Comment: just wondering , try to place the delete link in a separate column , maybe there are some issue of adding additional buttons inside a `<p:rowEditor />` column

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can't understand why you want me to move the component that works (id="delete") when my problem is with the facet component (id="header"). I could probably move the commandlink (id="create") elsewhere and it would work but it would mess up my gui design.  I'm wondering why, when it's wrapped in a facet, does the update fail (the ajax to the managed bean works - the database entry is proof)

Comment: sorry haven't seen that one , weird... have you tried to update the `materials` id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stephen, you're on the right track!
It was solved in a simpler way: I updated my dataTable list in managed bean - which I did for the delete but not for the insert. Massive oversight there. 
This code works:
`<p:commandLink id="create" value="Add new material" action="#{entityCrudTreeBean.createNewMaterial}" update=":formRight"/>`
Tip for people after me:  Primefaces 3.3 has a known issue concerning updating within the dataTable.  You need to wrap the dataTable with another component like a layout of a form.  Calling update on the wrapper works.
According to the primefaces blog from Aug 15, this has been fixed in 3.4.RC1.  But they changed the tree components.  I'll wait for the 3.4 final release before upgrading.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue as you a while back.

My working code looks like:

```
<f:facet name="header">Product List
<p:commandLink id="create" value="Add new product" ajax="true" process="@this" 
action="#{modelBean.save}" update="@form"/>
</f:facet>
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for sharing your code!  I've modified my code to `<f:facet id="header" name="header">
                        In-Cell Material Editing
                        <br />
                        <p:commandLink id="create" value="Add new material" ajax="true" process="@this" action="#{entityCrudTreeBean.createNewMaterial}" update="@form"/>
                    </f:facet>` but the problem of the component not refreshing is still there.

Comment: Maybe im being silly here. I think the problem possibly lies elsewhere and not necessarily in your xhtml.  Would you be able to post the entityCrudTreeBean and the entire xhtml page?